# Is there a way to make a random number in JavaScript and then take it and use it to make another random number?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I'm making a website for a fake company. One of the sections has a 'Stock Quote' feature that is just a random number. For this, I use the following code:

```
<p ID="stockcurrent"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("stockcurrent").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 200;
</script>
```

Now, what I want to do, is to take the number generated for that and use it to create a new number, that has as condition that it has to be equal or larger than the generated number. Ie, something like this:

```
<p ID="stockdayhigh"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("stockdayhigh").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + (the result of the stockcurrent script);
</script>
```

Is this something possible to do? My knowledge of JavaScript is pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use variables to achieve this

```
<p id="stockcurrent"></p>
<p id="stockdayhigh"></p>

<script>
    var stockCurrent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 200;
    var stockDayHigh = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + stockCurrent; 

    document.getElementById("stockcurrent").innerHTML = stockCurrent;
    document.getElementById("stockdayhigh").innerHTML = stockDayHigh;
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Another question - is it possible to calculate the diference (in %) between the 'current' and 'high' variable? That is, to say that the stock is up or down in x %, for example.

Comment: `var changeInPercentage = (stockDayHigh - stockCurrent)/stockCurrent * 100`

Answer (score 0):

If it is on the same page, you can reuse that number:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("stockdayhigh").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + document.getElementById("stockcurrent").innerHTML;
</script>
```

Comment: That's what variables are for.

Answer (score 0):

try this using condition

```
<p id="stockcurrent"></p>
<p id="stockdayhigh"></p>
<script>
    var rand=Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 200;
    var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 200)+200;

    document.getElementById("stockcurrent").innerHTML =rand;
    var curr=parseInt(document.getElementById("stockcurrent").innerText);

    if(curr>=rand2)
        document.getElementById("stockdayhigh").innerHTML =curr;
    else
    document.getElementById("stockdayhigh").innerHTML =rand+curr;

</script>
```